# HTTPS - IIS - Web Pages only Load Locally

Tags: iis, firewall, asp.net, https, windows-firewall

Summary of my Situation

- I am working with IIS (6.0) running on Microsoft Windows Server 2003
- Deploying an ASP.net website using HTTPS
- I have imported certs
- Web Pages load/work successfully when ran from the server itself
- I get "Connected to server X.X.X.X" in Firefox so it seems it can be found
- I get "The connection was Interrupted" in Firefox
- I get "The Page Cannot Be Displayed" in IE
- I cannot PING the remote server from the local machine (I get Request Timed out)
- Attempts using http yield the same results.

Since I seem to be "connected" but not allowed through I am assuming this is a firewall issue? I bring the question here because I would like to make sure I have exhausted all of my options and I did not overlook something.

All in all..

- Is this a firewall issue and should I be looking more into the server configuration?
- My local policy is pretty restrictive, could it be that this site is just not listed as trusted on my local machine? (I will need to reach an SA in order to change my local machines settings/trusted sites as well)
- Combination of both?
- Any more ideas on what I should check into?

**EDIT 1:** (McAfee Host Intrustion Prevention Error) (**EDIT 2:** Verified it is not this)

> Blocked Incoming UDP - Source X.X.X.X Destination X.X.X.X

Destination IP beginning octets are different than local machine and server location.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to ping a remote server, it may fail because of an intermediate firewall or a firewall at any end (local or remote) unless you are sure about any of the ends.

You need to confirm you can reach the server using telnet.

```
telnet your_server_ip port
```

You can try both ports 80 and 443. If you got connected, then that's fine. You are not blocked by IP. If you could not get connected (timeout), then it can be a firewall issue.

Also, are you using any proxy (configured or transparent)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. No proxy, telnet returns a blank screen so it seems it can connect (on both ports) but could this also mean a firewall could be stopping communication, or is it more likly its a local machine issue?

Comment: @harper89: If you are getting similar errors from other machines/locations, it should be an issue from the server.

Comment: I pulled an error from our HIPS and will edit. Thats the problem, every machine here is configured the exact same so I only have 1 way, 1 config to access it remotely. I will have to find permission to modify settings on the local machine. I will start there. Thanks for the tips